# What do vampires have to do with the phase of the moon?

Tags: tropes

I've seen a few animes that linked a vampire's powers to the phase of the moon. Where does this idea come from?

Are there actual Japanese myths about vampires that this stems from? Or something odd that got mixed in when the Western myth was translated into Japanese? Something else?

Comment: might help if you link, state, what animes you saw it from

Comment: i thought it was werewolves that was related to the moon..

Comment: @debal i think that's his point

Comment: @ton.yeung: I'm sure I've seen it more often than this, but off the top of my head I recall "Moon Phase" (which, admittedly, I didn't watch much of), as well as Evangeline A.K. McDowell from "Negima".

Comment: Perhaps you should ask on [scifi.se]

Comment: If we talk about the Nasuverse alone it's because Dead Apostles (the more common being that's refereed to as Vampires by the Church) come from True Ancestors who are products of Crimson Moon Brunestud, the Moon Aristotele (Ultimate One of The Moon) and since the phases is an indication on how long the moon is in the night sky a full moon would give Dead Apostles their [full power](http://typemoon.wikia.com/wiki/Moon_Cell#Effects_over_Vampires) (with it being around all night)

Comment: More generally speaking the Moon is like a motif for "night/darkness" while the sun is "day/light" and maybe it's similar as what blocking out the sun is for solar panels, blocking out the moon (as what gradually happens with the phases) reduces a vampire's power. however i haven't seen Moon Phase or Negima yet so i can't relate to them

Comment: As for japanese myths, the only thing that comes to mind is in Shinto with [Tsukuyomi-no-mikoto](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsukuyomi-no-Mikoto), the brother to Amaterasu, the Sun Goddess. i have no idea how these can be combined into a single answer so someone else can try if they want

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Full moons are traditionally 'spooky' and are often associated with mystical creatures from the 'darkness'.

Midnight during a full moon is called the *Witching hour* and is when these many of these creatures gain their full strength.

An obvious example of this is werewolves who transform under the full moon, but witches and other beings are affected also. A Halloween night (or *Samhain* as it was called in Ireland, where Halloween originates) with a full moon is when creatures abilities are at their most potent.

It is thought that this association was caused by the reactions that normal animals have with changes in the moon. (Birds get restless, dogs bark a lot, etc - much like [how animals can predict earthquakes](http://earthquake.usgs.gov/learn/topics/animal_eqs.php))

Bringing this back to vampires in particular, they also are affected by the phases of the moon. A full moon (and being well fed) will mean that their strength is at their fullest, whilst a moonless night could influence their desire for nourishment through blood.

You should also remember that in many tales of vampires, they cannot go out in the sun. The association could stem from simplifying the moon to be the 'opposite' of the sun.

**TLDR:** The moon is often used as a general source of power for many mystical creatures. But vampires are also known (outside anime) to be associated with the moon.

Comment: also, earlier vampire like Lord Ruthven (The Vampyre - 1819) and Varney (Varney the Vampire - 1845) were able to be healed by moonlight. Trust me, I'm a vampire.

Comment: @Darjeeling Shhh, don’t give away our secrets!